# Number format with a DOT as thousand separator in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dependencies, number-formatting

My Flutter source code displays number format with a comma like **1,234,567** VND. But I want to display it like **1.234.567** VND.

My app language is Vietnamese (vi_VN) so I like number format with a DOT.

So what have I to do?

I'm new to Flutter so could you please tell me exactly what's files to config?

Thank you very much!

Comment: you can simply replace commas with full stops.

Comment: @ManishDayma Can you please tell more details?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [NumberFormat.decimalPattern](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/NumberFormat-class.html) from [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package with your locale (in this case vi_VN)

```
var formatter = NumberFormat.decimalPattern('vi_VN');
print(formatter.format(1234567));
```

Output

```
1.234.567
```

Comment: @DevMMO you should still use English even in the comment section. You need to post the code that are related to the question so people can give you an accurate solution/ advice.

Answer (score 0):

here is how you can **replace** commas in your string with full stops.

```
String old = "1,234,567 VND";
String newString = old.replaceAll(",", ".");
```

the newString will be **1.234.567 VND**

Comment: What's files to put these codes, sir? @Manish Dayma

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, and use [**replaceAll**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/replaceAll.html) method

```
void main() {
  String baseString = "1,234,567 VND";
  String newString = baseString.replaceAll(",", ".");
  print(newString);
}
```

Output:`1.234.567 VND`

Result-> [image]